# How to grep only one line with matching one string. BASH

Tags: bash

I want to grep only one line from below example :

```
    STRING1     EXAMPLE1   EXAMPLE2
    STRING2     EXAMPLE1   EXAMPLE2
    STRING3     EXAMPLE1   EXAMPLE2
```

I want to have only output from grep command :

```
    STRING3     EXAMPLE1   EXAMPLE2
```

Which argument I need to do in grep command to grep only "STRING3" ?

Thank you for help.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and how did it fail? Edit your question to include your code attempt(s) in a code block.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/  http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ https://ss64.com/bash/grep.html -- what's wrong with `grep STRING3 file`?

Answer (score 0):

First, your question should be better defined and always remember that you don't need to post an answer to clarify things, you can edit your quest.

Regarding your question you should use grep to filter lines that start with STRING3 in your case you have 4 spaces and then STRING3 so you should keep that in mind.

```
grep '^    STRING3' test.txt
```

Overall I would suggest using sed or awk instead of grep because your case seems a bit complicated.

Comment: Its not what i need to achieve. There are columns, not spaces.
I want to use either grep or sed but need to know how.

Comment: What do you mean by columns? Could you explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, I mean if Im trying to grep with spaces then there is no output.

Comment: Okay probably there is a tabbing issue. To overcome this you should (in case you don't need the exact number of spaces) truncate all spaces (that create a tab) into one and then grep. Command: cat test.txt | tr -s ' ' | grep '^ STRING3'